# Wordpress won't let me wrap a div in an a tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having a very strange issue that I can't figure out. I'm working on a custom theme in wordpress and I've got a div with an image and another icon image inside.
I'm trying to make both the whole image and the icon image within it a link.

The issue is that when I try to put a link around the whole div, Wordpress closed the link prematurely and then adds a second link - neither of which are actually enclosing my div. 
If I change the div to a span, it will let me wrap it in a link. Why?! What is going on and how and I turn off this 'feature'?

Here is the selected code in my template file:

```
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="img">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                    <img style="display: none;" src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_title()); ?>">
                    <span class="zoom hide-ie"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($categories): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($categories[0] -> term_id )?>" class="category-link"><?php echo $categories[0]->cat_name?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="background" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>');"></div>
            </div>
         </a>
```

However, this is the code that is being outputted to the browser:

```
  <a href="http:somelink">
    </a>
  <div class="img">
    <a href="http:somelink">
      <img style="display: none;" src="imagelink.jpg" alt="This isn’t our beautiful contest – how did we get here?">
      <span class="zoom hide-ie"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
    </a>
    <a href="categorylink/" class="category-link">Agency Mojo</a>
    <div class="background" style="background-image: url('http://imagelink.jpg');"></div>
  </div>
```

So as you can see, it's closing the link immediately, and then adding another link inside of the `

Any help would be amazing as I've seen this question asked but not answered in a few other places including [here on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427948/why-is-my-wordpress-post-loop-auto-closing-anchor-tags-and-not-wrapping-the-elem)

Comment: The link should go inside the div, then just set it to `display:block;`

Comment: That does not solve the problem - the a tag is still getting closed prematurely and the second one is still getting created and also closing early

Comment: I tried to edit by previous comment but lost connection. The actual problem is that (like `DeFeNdog` says)  you have nested `a`  tags. Those are invalid. While the `html` output you get from worpress might be the way you expected, the browser will change it so that the DOM will valid. Thats why it is changed that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally try to avoid nesting anchor tags. Perhaps something like this would work better.

```
<div class="img">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img style="display: none;" src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_title()); ?>" />
            <span class="zoom hide-ie"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($categories): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($categories[0]-> term_id ); ?>" class="category-link">
            <?php echo $categories[0]->cat_name; ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="background" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>');"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```